USE LIKE or CONTAINS to search two different column in one column IN SSRS
Hello guys i want to check if a two column are contained in an other column with using Like or contains statement. in ssrs report
for example:
column1 is name
column2 is lastname
column3 is fullname

Then how do i do i check if column 1 or column2 are in column 3
this is what i have been using so far:
iif((Fields!column3.value).lower().tostring.contains(lcase("*" & (Field!column1.value)&"*") or (Fields!column3.value).lower().tostring.contains(lcase("*" & (Field!column2.value)&"*"),"yes","No")


Don't worry about the length of this answer, the expression you need is right at the end but I wanted to talk you thru the process...
Let's take the following dataset query as our sample data
SELECT 'Dave' as column1, 'Smith' as column2, 'Dave Smith' as column3
UNION SELECT 'Bob', 'Jones', 'Bob'
UNION SELECT 'John', 'Smith', 'Mark Moore'
UNION SELECT 'Harry', 'Lomax', 'Mike Lomax'
UNION SELECT 'Rob', 'Taylor', 'Robin Banks'

Using a basic expression we can test if either of the values in columns 1 or 2 are in column 3.
= IIF(
        LCASE(Fields!column3.Value).Contains(RTRIM(LTRIM(LCASE(Fields!column1.Value))))
        OR
        LCASE(Fields!column3.Value).Contains(RTRIM(LTRIM(LCASE(Fields!column2.Value))))
        , "Yes"
        , "No"
        )

Here I've set the value to lower case and trimmed trailing and leading spaces from the column1 and 2 values before comparison.
This works to an extent but as you can see in the final results (below) "Rob" is found, whereas the actual name in column 3 is "Robin". This results is shown in "test1"
To resolve this, I've split the full name using space as the delimiter and then joined the resulting array back together again with a pipe | symbol. I've wrapped the whole thing in pipe symbols also, using this expression
="|" & JOIN(SPLIT(Fields!column3.Value, " "),"|") & "|"

You can see the result of this in "test2".
Finally in test3, I've combined the two expression and also wrapped the column 1 and 2 values with pipes. This means we can handle name that match at the start and end correctly.
Here is the final expression
= IIF(
        LCASE("|" & JOIN(SPLIT(Fields!column3.Value, " "),"|") & "|").Contains("|" & RTRIM(LTRIM(LCASE(Fields!column1.Value))) & "|")
        OR
        LCASE("|" & JOIN(SPLIT(Fields!column3.Value, " "),"|") & "|").Contains("|" & RTRIM(LTRIM(LCASE(Fields!column2.Value))) & "|")
        , "Yes"
        , "No"
        )

This gives the following results.


Hello Dear @Alan, thanks you so very much for your answer. Much appraciated. Given to your example, how then if in column 1 we have two string separated by comma or space or also comma and space
column1    Column2  Column 3
Bob hey      Jones         Bob hey Jones
Bob, Hey     Jones         Bob, hey Jones
Bob,Hey      Jones         Bob,Hey Jones

Edit your question and show examples  of data and the expected result. Show the example data as script like I did in the answer as this makes it easier to replicate.
